# Submit multiple input values

Tags: javascript

Im passing the value from Sweetalert Popup to the Form and i get the input sended to me per email.
As i have multiple options to let the user give his input, only the last input get submitted.
Creating a Javascript Array and submit those as JSON would help me here in this instance?

```js
// TextArea

var TextAreas = document.getElementsByClassName('bemerkung')
// go through all elements with the same ClassName
for (var i = 0; i < TextAreas.length; i++) {
  var TextArea = TextAreas[i]
  TextArea.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: '<strong>Bemerkung</strong>',
      input: 'textarea',
      inputPlaceholder: "Wir geben unser Bestes den Wunsh zu erfüllen"
    }).then(result => {
      var string = result.value;

      // target iframe inside index.php
      var iframe = document.getElementById('checkout')
      // get iframe content
      var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      // Creating a new hidden input node in that target form;  
      var bemerkung = innerDoc.getElementById('f36')
      bemerkung.value = string
    });
  })
}
```

```css
.bemerkung {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5df78d3035688c75f8199fe6/5f3830b87c03d7ae736cc485_pen%20loading-editing.svg);
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="bemerkung w-button" type="button"></button>
<br>
<button class="bemerkung w-button" type="button"></button>
<br>
<button class="bemerkung w-button" type="button"></button>
<br>
<button class="bemerkung w-button" type="button"></button>


<iframe src="Checkout/form.html" scrolling="yes" id="checkout" style="min-width:280px;width:100%;height:600px;border:none;" frameborder="none" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>




<!-- Modal Popup-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this bug is caused by function scope.
Try replace `var` with `let` within `for (let i = 0)`

Comment: If you don't use some bundle tools, you need to make other workarounds. Any problem,  comment here

Comment: no that's not the issue here. By giving more than 1 input the previous one gets overwrite by the current one. So at the end only the last input gets send.